# IIS Client Certificate Mapping module not running

Tags: windows, iis, certificate, windows-server-2019

I am using IIS 10 with Windows server 2019, and am trying to authenticate a user with IIS Client certificate mapping.
When Tracing the failed requests, I do not see the IIS Client Certificate mapping module, therefore I guess it is not even running, and not that it fails to authenticate the user(probably not wrong credentials/certificate).
I have installed the 'IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication' in the server manager, and configured the certificates to the appropriate user in the Default Website's configuration editor`(system.webServer\security\authentication\iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication - oneToOneMappings)`.

I tried reentering the mapping properties, made sure the IIsClientCertificateMapping property is enabled and installed. I am having the same 401 error code

Is there anything I might be missing? Thanks :)

Comment: Vague descriptions alone do not allow community members to understand the problem you are experiencing. Please provide details about the 401 error.